# TileMill-style based on the country the objects belong to

Tags: layers, style, tilemill

Is it possible to have different TileMill stylings in different countries? I need for instance different colours for highways based on the country the highway is in. 
Is there a best practice solution to this problem? I know it's possible to store the borders of all countries in PostGIS an check the intersection of an object with all countries. I could also precalulate the corresponding country for all objects like in Nominatim. Are there any better solutions?